# Regularly Maintained Javascript Library For Selecting A Date From A Pop-Up Calendar?

Tags: javascript, css, calendar

I'm doing some maintenance on a legacy webapp.   The app uses a 3rd party javascript for displaying a pop-up calendar when the user puts her/his mouse into an HTML textfield.  The user clicks the date on the calendar and the date gets inserted into the HTML text field.

I've noticed some anomalous behavior so I decided to investigate the script.   It looks like it was last updated by the developer in 2007: http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Forms-and-Controls-C-C/Dynamic-Date-Selector-22508.html

I think I would like to replace this script with a javascript that does the same thing, but is part of an open source project that is regularly maintained and possibly with a community around it.   My preference is either to get a project that does just that feature or a project that will make implementing just feature easy.......I don't want to gut the javascripts in a legacy webapp unless I have to.

So, can anyone recommend an open source, regularly maintained javascript library that has such a feature?

Thanks much in advance

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) - from jQuery UI library - very solid and popular.

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered.  Thank you!!

Comment: I'm still new to stackoverflow.  I clicked on the checkmark user the number for your comment to accept it as the answer.  Please let me know if you don't get the credit or points.  Steve

Comment: You have done everything correctly, Steve. I am glad my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [date picker of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).